# Convert LinQ var into a DataTable in C# getting 'specified cast is not valid' Exception

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

I'm trying to load the Linq into DataTable in C#. I used below code but while compiling I'm getting `specified cast is not valid` Exception.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("MobileNumber", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("FatherName", typeof(int));
var results =
    from table1 in tree.AsEnumerable()
    join table2 in direct.AsEnumerable()
        on (int)table1["ID"] equals (int)table2["ID"]
select new
{
    ID = (int)table1["ID"],
    Name = (int)table1["Name"],
    MobileNumber = (int)table1["MobileNumber"],
    Address = (int)table2["Address"],
    FatherName = (int)table2["FatherName"],
};
foreach (var item in results)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ID"] = item.ID;
    dr["Name"] = item.Name;
    dr["MobileNumber"] = item.MobileNumber;
    dr["Address"] = item.Address;
    dr["FatherName"] = item.FatherName;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Comment: which line is causing the Exception?

Comment: #Line **foreach (var item in results)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your columns are of type int.  I will assume name, mobile number, and FatherName are a string.

Comment: Thats not the reason. I will get exception when the cursor reach this line itself. #Line foreach (var item in results)

Comment: Because that line is where you evaluate `results`, which is where you attempt a series of blind casts.